# System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"

Tags: rest-api, callout

while we are making a callout to external system we are getting the below error:

```
System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"
```

I have googled and find out that External system needs to Whitelisted the Salesforce IP address.

External system has already Whitelisted the all salesforce IP Address but still we are getting this error.